# Concurrencia en Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Estoy montando un proyecto en java con spring batch.

Tengo un trabajo con un reader, un processor y un writer. La idea es recibir un fichero de entrada, dividirlo antes de hacer nada por ejemplo en 2 partes, y luego lanzar en paralelo el proceso para que tarde menos.

Tengo esto:

```
*@Bean
// @formatter:off
public Job job() {
return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
.start(splitFlow())
.build() //builds FlowJobBuilder instance
.build(); //builds Job instance
}
@Bean
public Flow splitFlow() {
return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("splitFlow")
.split(taskExecutor())
.add(flow1(), flow2())
.build();
}
@Bean
public Flow flow1() {
return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow1")
.start(stepLine1())
.build();
}
@Bean
public Flow flow2() {
return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow2")
.start(stepLine2())
.build();
}
@Bean
public Flow flow3() {
return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow3")
.start(stepLine3())
.build();
}
@Bean
public Flow flow4() {
return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow4")
.start(stepLine4())
.build();
}
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
}
@Bean
// @formatter:off
public Step stepLine1() {
return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepLine1").listener(new GenericListener())
.<LineFile, NormalizedLine>chunk(100)
.reader(readerLineFile1())
.processor(processorLineFile1())
.writer(writerLineFile1())
.build();
}
@Bean
// @formatter:off
public Step stepLine2() {
return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepLine1").listener(new GenericListener())
.<LineFile, NormalizedLine>chunk(100)
.reader(readerLineFile1())
.processor(processorLineFile1())
.writer(writerLineFile1())
.build();
}*
```

Y la historia que aparentemente funciona bien, porque lo hace por separado cada procesamiento. Pero el proceso me tarda lo mismo haciendolo secuencial que lanzandolo con 2 procesos en paralelo, lo cual no le veo ningún sentido.

¿Se os ocurre por qué puede ser?

Muchas Gracias, un saludo!!!!

Comment: This is [es.so]. Spanish, please. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta al castellano, de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Perdona, ya está cambiado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que el problema esta en que no has configurado correctamente el taskExecutor.

En tu código, estás utilizando SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor, pero podrías considerar utilizar un ThreadPoolTaskExecutor con un pool de hilos configurado. Algo así:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5); // ajusta según sea necesario
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10); // ajusta según sea necesario
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("spring_batch_thread");
    taskExecutor.initialize();
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

Si no te soluciona te dejo un par de cosas que puedes probar ademas de esto:

1. **Configuración de particionamiento:**
   El particionamiento en Spring Batch puede ser otra opción para procesar datos en paralelo. Puedes dividir tu archivo en varias particiones y procesarlas en paralelo. Asegúrate de configurar correctamente el particionamiento y de que la lógica de particionamiento sea eficiente para tu caso de uso.
2. **Configuración de la tarea de chunking:**
   Asegúrate de que la configuración de chunking sea adecuada para el procesamiento en paralelo. En tu código, ambos stepLine1 y stepLine2 parecen tener la misma configuración (chunk(100)), lo cual podría no ser óptimo si están procesando el mismo conjunto de datos. Ajusta la configuración del chunk según sea necesario.
3. **Configuración de los flujos:**
   Asegúrate de que los flujos paralelos estén realmente ejecutando en paralelo. Podrías considerar revisar la configuración de la ejecución en paralelo y asegurarte de que los flujos se estén ejecutando de manera independiente.
4. **Monitorización del rendimiento:**
   Utiliza herramientas de monitorización del rendimiento para identificar cuellos de botella y analizar el rendimiento de tu aplicación.

Si nada de esto soluciona ponme un comentario